# Why I can't pass angularJS parameter on onClick html event?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to concat a string with a AngularJS expression in html. See the example above:

```js
angular.module("app", []);
function MyCtrl($scope){
    $scope.item = "Hello";
    $scope.say = function(text){
        alert(text);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function openFunctionJS(param){
        alert(param);
    };
</script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <a ng-click="say(item + ' World')">Say {{item}} World by ngclick</a><br/>
    <a onclick="openFunctionJS('{{item}}')">Say {{item}} World by onclick</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/murphycwb/zr3cc4od/

But it doesn't work. My entire function is in JavaScript and I don't want to change it right now if possible.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error thrown by AngularJS is quite specific when you try to do this

> Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.  Please
>   use the ng- versions

This is not problematic though, for the framework offers `ng-` solutions for these events. I see you're already using `ng-click`, so why not leverage it to solve this as well? If your goal is to keep `openFunctionJS` untouched, no problem- just call it within `$scope.say`. Here is an idea...

**note** - I have altered your definition for `MyCtrl`. Use of global functions as controllers is generally discouraged

```
<script>
function openFunctionJS(param) {
    alert(param); // this is called inside $scope.say()
};
</script>

<a ng-click="say(item + ' World')">Say {{item}} World from ng-click</a>
```

---

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.item = 'Hello';
    $scope.say = function(text) {
        openFunctionJS(text)
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/k0dLbhea/) - working demo

Comment: Thanks man, works perfectly! But, only for knowledge, Is there any way to do that while keeping the onclick?

Comment: through markup - no. Thats what events like `ng-click`, `ng-blur` etc are for